# How many $3$-digit even numbers less than $700$ can be formed from the digits $0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8$ if repetition of digits is not allowed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider the digits $0,2,4,5,6,8$. How many $3$-digit even numbers less than $700$ can be formed if repetition of digits is not allowed? Note the first digit can't be zero.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have an answer which you want to double check? Please add your working to the question always, since it helps people answer your question better. If you have no working to show, then try to form some three digit numbers from the set, and see if you get any pattern.

Comment: The very first thing is to choose the first digit (the hundreds digit). Because it cannot be zero, the only options left are $2, 4, 5,6$. Surely, you can continue from here.

Answer (score 4):

Even Number will end with $\left \{ 0,2,4,6 \text{  or  }8 \right \}$.

---

Let us divide the possiblities of even number with number less than $700$ in $3$ parts.

- Ending with $0$
- Ending with $\left \{ 2,4 \text{  or  }6 \right \}$.
- Ending with $8$.

> - Ending with $0$

$3$ digit number possible$= \underbrace{4}_{\text{4 choices among  2,4,5,6}} \times  \underbrace{4}_{\text{4 choices among  2,4,5,6,8}} \times 1$

> - Ending with $\left \{ 2,4 \text{  or  }6 \right \}=
>    \underbrace{3}_{\text{3 choices among  2,4,5,6}} \times  \underbrace{4}_{\text{4 choices among  0,2,4,5,6,8}} \times \underbrace{3}_{\text{3 choices among  2,4,6}}$

---

> - Ending with $8$
>     $= \underbrace{4}_{\text{4 choices among  2,4,5,6}} \times  \underbrace{4}_{\text{4 choices among  0,2,4,5,6}} \times 1$

$=16+36+16=68$

Comment: In your second case, you wrote $4$ choices among $2, 4, 5, 6$ but wrote $3$ for the number of choices.  The number of choices for the hundreds digit depends on whether or not $8$ is the units digit.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sir.Sorry it was a typo.

Comment: for the second case, i am first selecting units place by $4$ ways and then selecting the thousand's pace by $3$ ways$

Comment: If the units digit is $8$, then you have four choices for the hundreds digit: $2$, $4$, $5$, $6$.  On the other hand, if the units digit is $2$, $4$, or $6$, the restriction that the number is less than $700$ means you only have three choices for the units digit: $5$ or the two even numbers among $2$, $4$, or $6$ that has not been used in the units digit.  I suggest you use three cases:  units digit is $0$; units digit is $2$, $4$, or $6$; units digit is $8$.

Comment: edited .Although i am afraid if my answer is correct!

Comment: If the units digit is $2$, $4$, or $6$, then $8$ is a potential tens digit.  The other two cases are correct.

Comment: thanks a lot .i have edited it

Comment: You have a typographical error for the middle case.  You meant to multiply by $4$ choices for the tens digit.  Otherwise, everything is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let the set of $3$ digit even numbers be represented by _ _ _.

Last digit can be $0, 2, 4, 6 \text{ or } 8$; rest $2$ digits can be anything among remaining $5$ digits (including the digit $5$) $\implies 5 \times 5 \times 4 = 80$. That's the total number of 3 digit even numbers formed by these digits.  But we also counted $3$-digit numbers starting with $0$ or $8$, count the number of such integers and subtract.

Comment: We want the number of $3$-digit even numbers less than $700$ that can be formed from the given digits without repetition.  Why are you adding the one-digit and two-digit numbers to the total?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes, there is no need for that

Answer (score 2):

The first digit can be either 2,4,5 or 6

The second digit can be any of the digits

The last digit can be any of the digits except 5

Case 1: When first digit is 5. $$Number\ of\ ways\ = 1*5*4=20$$
Case 2: When first digit is not 5 and second digit is 5. $$Number\ of\ ways\ = 3*1*4=12$$

Case 3: When neither first not second digit is 5.
$$Number\ of\ ways\ = 3*4*3=36$$

Total number of ways= $36+12+20=68$